# Extra income in UK?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I am a UK resident and have a permanent job in the UK for which I received monthly salary in £. I recently did a one-off consultancy abroad for which I received about £1000 commission (in Euro currency) and all expenses paid.

I've been told that under the UK trading allowance, I can make an extra £1000 without the need to report this. Is this correct or how should I report this to the tax office?

Comment: Is this the same company you work for in the UK that you got the "commission" from or a totally different one.

Comment: @Neuromancer a totally different one. It was a one of consultancy gig with no direct relation to my employer.

Answer (score 1):

As found on [gov.uk/income-tax](https://www.gov.uk/income-tax):

> **You do not pay tax on things like:**
>
> - the first £1,000 of income from self-employment - this is your ‘trading allowance’

Although you haven't said that the £1,000 was through self-employment, so you will need to declare it as the website also says:

> **You pay tax on things like:**
>
> - money you earn from employment
> - profits you make if you’re self-employed - including from services you sell through websites or apps

So the answer is kind of dependant on how you're setup and how you made the money, but this should be enough to get you started and point you in the right direction.